# Locate items with no changes over a period of time

Tags: sql-server

Is there a T-SQL query that would allow me to see products that have had no changes in quantity for the past 4 days?

| Product | Date | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Coke | 2022-04-06 | 0 |
| Coke | 2022-04-07 | 0 |
| Coke | 2022-04-08 | 0 |
| Coke | 2022-04-09 | 0 |
| Pepsi | 2022-04-06 | 0 |
| Pepsi | 2022-04-07 | 1 |
| Pepsi | 2022-04-08 | 1 |
| Pepsi | 2022-04-09 | 1 |
| Sprite | 2022-04-06 | 1 |
| Sprite | 2022-04-07 | 0 |
| Sprite | 2022-04-08 | 0 |
| Sprite | 2022-04-09 | 1 |
| Tango | 2022-04-05 | 2 |
| Tango | 2022-04-06 | 1 |
| Tango | 2022-04-07 | 1 |
| Tango | 2022-04-08 | 1 |
| Tango | 2022-04-09 | 1 |

Result

| Product | Quantity |
| --- | --- |
| Coke | 0 |

Edit: this is how I started off my code

```
DECLARE @CurrentDate date = GETDATE();
DECLARE @PreviousDate date = DATEADD (Day, -4, @CurrentDate)
DECLARE @Quantity AS Decimal(8,5)
DECLARE @Count AS int

SELECT  
    [Date], [Product], [Quantity]
FROM 
    Table1
WHERE
    [Date] = @PreviousDate 
    AND [Product] IN (SELECT [Product]
                      FROM Table1
                      WHERE [DATE] BETWEEN @PreviousDate AND @CurrentDate)
```

Comment: No there is no SQL statement, but one can be created. What did you try, and why did that fail (which might be the reason for you asking this question) 

Comment: Why is Pepsi not in the result? It has same `Quantity` for 3 days?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you could use `first_value()` analytic function to partition the products accordingly and check the first and last quantities match,

```
select distinct product, quantity from (
    select *, 
        First_Value(quantity) over(partition by product order by date) f, 
        First_Value(quantity) over(partition by product order by date desc) l
    from t
    where date >= DateAdd(day,-4,GetDate())
)t
where f = l;
```

[Demo Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a4ab6de4a7a1f80937613cf13282ecbc)

**Edit**

Seems I didn't quite understand but do now (I hope) so how about an approach using *not exists*?

```
with cv as (
    select *, 
        First_Value(quantity) over(partition by product order by date desc) currentValue,
        Count(*) over(partition by product) qty
    from t
    where date >= DateAdd(day,-4,GetDate())
)
select distinct product, quantity
from cv t
where qty=4 and not exists (
  select * from cv t2
    where t2.product = t.product 
    and t2.quantity != currentValue
);
```

[Demo Fiddle (2)](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d8d98f1462439455cbbbd25c0d584706)

Comment: I would still need it to go through each day.  I added more data to the table to give an example.

Comment: @Jared.1773 I've edited and proposed an alternative solution now you've elaborated more. Does this work for you?

Comment: it's very close - but if I add another product on for 4/5 with a different quantity, it still shows up.  [Demo Fiddle (3)](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=66e67042f28ccbec71d2fdcdc2fa63ff)

Comment: @Jared.1773 I over-complicated it - have modified to move the date-comparision to the CTE where it should have been!

Comment: It's so very close, but there needs to be a check to make sure that the product was actually there 4 days ago.

Comment: @Jared.1773 One final edit then, assuming one row per product per day as you've shown you could add a windowed count and check it's 4 (or whatever period of days you're looking over). - check edit again.

Answer (score 1):

You select all records from `@PreviousDate` (`WHERE [Date] = @PreviousDate`)  and which have modifications  (`AND [Product] IN (...)`)

```
SELECT  
    t1.[Date], t1.[Product], t1.[Quantity], t2.Quantity  "PreviousQuantity"
FROM 
    Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table1 t2 On t1.Product = t2.Product and t2.[Date] = @PreviousDate
WHERE t1.[Date] = @CurrentDate
  and t1.Quantity = t2.Quantity
```

But this will show nothing because `@PreviousDate` has the value `2022-04-05`  (when @CurrentDate=`2022-04-09`)

So, you might need to change @PreviousDate to: `DECLARE @PreviousDate date = DATEADD (Day, -3, @CurrentDate)`

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1fbe1c7785b0d3986a8daf137110bbe9)

Comment: the query doesn't loop through each date. I added more data to the table to give an example.